# ASP/AJAX Tab Control Not Displayed on Website but Showing Up Fine Locally

Tags: asp.net, ajax, tabs

I am just starting with the ASP programming. Wondering, what is the best approach to figure out what is wrong? I added a tab control from the ASP.NET/AJAX Control Toolkit. It works great locally, but when I upload it to the website, the tab control is not showing up and the busy cursor is up for ~10 seconds. I do not see any details/error messages from the website. When deploying, the toolkit dll is being uploaded.

Comment: Try checking in firebug for any client side errors and also event viewer on server machine for any server side errors.

Comment: Thanks Sundeep! Also, as an additional point, this is with IIS8.

Comment: Perhaps the better question is, will this control work with IIS 8? I just tried a basic new project with the control integrated using first .NET 4.0 and .NET 4.5 and neither worked. Ideas greatly appreciated?

Comment: FYI
Went to an earlier version of the control which is working.